# Is it more efficient to initialize objects or read/write directly from/to the database?

Tags: database, sqlite, optimization, orm, loading

I'm creating an app that uses a SQLite database to store it's data. The application is similar to a task app, where it mostly just grabs and displays data and updates it when needed.

My question is whether it is worth it to initialize separate objects (which I would assume would happen when the app is loading), or whether it's better to simply read/write values from/to the database directly.

I've seen both methods used, but my intuition says it would be much cheaper to interface with the database directly, as there would be less memory overhead, and the values will have to be read from/saved to the database eventually anyway, but perhaps running queries every time data is loaded or updated would be slower than interacting with objects.

As for constraints, I am using a SQLite database over an ORM as I would like the code and data store to be as cross-platform as possible, and I haven't found any ORMs that interface with Python, (Obj-)C, and java, which are the target languages I'm using. If anyone has any suggestions that work with each of the languages, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think caching will help, especially for objects that will be needed often (like users - permissions).

You can use a mode like this on the objects that you want stored in cache and later on easily set this cache on/off at any time (for java I recommend ehcache):

```
getObject (key){
  if(object present in cache) return object from cache;
  load object from database;
  store it to cache;
  return object
}
```

Mihai

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But I wonder, is this any different from simply creating and initializing objects? Since if you have a cache, you now have to maintain the integrity of the cached object as well as the database values.

Comment: It all depends on your application, this is why I have proposed you the test. In my opionion caching is always good, at least for parts of the object model. Your won't need to intialize/destroy so may objects and if you will need the database for more serious things than easy getters, keeping a cache will reduce its load. Also, if your application grows you might need later on to move to another solution like MySQL or Oracle on a separate server.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the cache will help, especially if you have a large number of concurrent accesses to your application.

Each time you have to go to the webserver you loose time (you need to go to another application, usually to a different server, transport the data back and forward). Accessing a local object is much faster.

The easiest solution is to try this with cache on/off for a class like Users and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. With SQLite though, the database is just a file, and the server is embedded locally in the application, so it is basically reading a local file, which I would expect to take about the same amount of time to access the data (however maybe not the same amount organizing and filtering the results).

Answer (score 0):

If the database is not *too* big, I'd suggest you to (create and) use the in-memory style of SQLite database; you can have a look at [this](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) just to begin with. Plus, after you are done with accessing/writing to the database in memory, you can always dump it to a file to be used later; loading and saving an SQLite database to memory and disk respectively is pretty straightforward using `sqlite3_backup_init()`, `sqlite3_backup_step()` and `sqlite3_backup_finish()` as is given [here](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html).

(I am not clear as to what functionality you require in an ORM.)